# What kind of SPARQL patterns result in multisets (or sequences) of solution mappings

Tags: sparql

I am doing some SPARQL proofs where I use multisets to establish the proofs (instead of patterns). When applying the results in actual SPARQL queries, I need to make sure that every pattern used produces a multiset so that my proofs still hold.

**EXAMPLE**

Let `JOIN` be the SPARQL `JOIN` (aka `AND`) operator, and `eval` be the evaluation function.

*Lemma A:* Assume two multisets of solution mappings; M1 and M2: I made the proof that `JOIN(M1, M2) = JOIN(M2, M1)`.

In order to apply this in an actual query (in algebraic form): `JOIN(P1, P2) ≡ JOIN(P2, P1)` which is correct if `eval((JOIN(P1, P2)) = eval(JOIN(P2, P1))` which can be written as `JOIN(eval(P1), eval(P2() ≡ JOIN(eval(P2), eval(P1))`. In order to use *Lemma A*, it needs to hold that `eval(P1)` and `eval(P2)` yield multisets of solution mappings. However, not all SPARQL patterns yield multisets of solution mappings (I am not talking about sequences here as a sequence can be converted into a multiset). For example `GROUP BY` yields a set of mappings from solution mappings to multisets of solution mappings.

**QUESTION**

Which constraints on the structures of P1 and P2 I need to impose in order to ensure that, e.g., my *Lemma A*, is applicable?

Comment: why should any evaluation of a graph pattern not yield a multiset? What are you trying to show in your proof? that a join of two graph patterns is symmetric?

Comment: The SPARQL 1.1 specification classifies a GROUP BY pattern as a graph pattern. However, GROUP BY does not yield a multiset of solution mappings. Whereas it may not be syntactically correct to use  GROUP BY in a join without aggregation, in the algebra, as far as I am concerned, there is nothing that prevents it.

The proof I mention for JOIN is only an example for illutstration.

Comment: GROUP BY is one part of the syntax where aggregates form another part with other syntax in the SELECT clause. The SELECT makes the multiset (and a set of multisetwith all the elements having cardinality 1).

"Group" is part of process and it the AggregateJoin that produces the multiset. See Section 18.2.4.1 - the translation ends with AggregateJoin.

Comment: Absolutely correct. However, I find it strange why the evaluation semantics takes a graph pattern (section 18.6) and at the same time, GRUOP BY is a graph pattern. Which, theoretically, means you can, e.g., evaluate a join of a GROUP BY pattern with any other graph pattern. (See in section 18.6: 'eval(D(G), Join(P1, P2)) = Join(eval(D(G), P1), eval(D(G), P2))' and at the beginning of the section 'P, P1, P2 : graph patterns'.